# Wordpress listed as a web browser in google analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

We have users that manage to bypass javascript form validation and we see in google analytics that they all share a common web browser... "Wordpress". What does it mean ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

'Wordpress' most likely means it’s an automated request. WordPress provides an API for making HTTP calls, WP_Http, and its requests will be shown as 'WordPress' in analytics (but this can be overriden).

'Automated' doesn’t mean it’s malicious. WordPress sites can have valid reasons to access your site (for example, to check for dead links). The fact that ‘WordPress’ accesses your site doesn’t mean anything bad per se.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I thought about that but it's not possible because people on "wordpress" browser have send us emails using the contact form on the website with valid content (not spam).